# overflow-y gets applied to every page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm new react developer. Here iI have two pages page 'A' & page 'B', and above them is `<Header />` ,

My question is I'm in page 'B' and I want to have `overflow-y: hidden` to the whole page, but it is not working, but if i put that inside `body { overflow-y: hidden }` then it will work but it will apply that to every page which is what I don't want. This is how i set my css,
A.css & B.css and then importing them

App.js:

```
 return (
    <div className="app">
     <Header />
      <Switch>
<AuthenticatedRoute
          path="/A"
          enabled={user?.isAdmin }
        >
          <A />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
        <AuthenticatedRoute
          path="/B/"
          enabled={user?.isAdmin }
        >
          <B />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>
</Switch

</div>
```

Comment: you can write  body{overflow-y:hidden} inside page B styles

Comment: You will have to set overflow on each page.

Comment: I don't understand what you'd like to have. Do you want to change the styling of `Header` if you're on route B or change the style of the container with css class `app` on that route?

Comment: @Allure  setting overflow with body {} on page A also affects Page B, and if i set overflow on both of them it will either unset other... why ?

Comment: @AshRingler for some reason when i set body{overflow-y:hidden} in page A and body{overflow-scroll} on page B both of them become body{overflow-y:hidden}, one pages style affects other page also

Comment: Why are you setting global styles if you don't want styles to effect globally? In other words, don't set styles on the body if you don't want them globally set. Each page should set its own style rules. Can you update question to include how you are attempting to style components?

Comment: @DrewReese it seems to be automatically global, here what i found : 'Create react app will bundle all your css files into one so all the styles will be available everywhere in you app (on every rendered component).' so how to set styles on one page without affecting other ?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to style the body then you can use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-body-classname to set a challenge depending on the page and set the styles on that class css